# Shifting buffer via memcpy

Tags: c

I wrote following 2 ltrim functions (function which removes white-spaces from left side of the string):

**1**. (putting here this code to not get such code as an answer)

```
void ltrim(char * str, int size)
{
    char const *start = str;
    char const *end = start + size;
    for(;*start && (*start==' ' || *start=='\n' || *start=='\r' || *start=='\t');++start);

    while(start != end)
    {
        *str = *start;
        ++start;
        ++str;
    }
    *str='\0';
}
```

**2**.

```
void ltrim(char * str, int size)
{
    char const *start = str;
    char const *end = start + size;
    for(;*start && (*start==' ' || *start=='\n' || *start=='\r' || *start=='\t');++start);
    memcpy(str, start, end-start);
    *(str + (end - start)) = '\0';
}
```

Does second version safe?

P.S. I have tried and it works, but not sure that memcpy is safe in this case.

Comment: Hint: check the [`isspace()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/isspace.html) function with prototype in `<ctype.h>` :)

Comment: @pmg I don't need isspace. for me this 4 characters are ok to be checked.

Comment: Other than strange (unicode) characters, isspace only accounts for `'\f'` and `'\v'` more ... and your code looks more beautiful: `for (; *start && isspace((unsigned char)*start); ++start);`

Comment: You could also simplify the check to `*start && strchr(" \n\r\t", *start)`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When source and destination overlap you should use [memmove](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memmove) rather than [memcpy](http://linux.die.net/man/3/memcpy).

From the memcpy man page:

`The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area src to memory area dest. The memory areas should not overlap. Use memmove(3) if the memory areas do overlap.`

Comment: Also, this guy should check that `start` never goes beyond `start+size`, and that `start != NULL`.

Comment: Nope, sorry @Mihran, but `start` can go beyond `size`.  `size` may not be the end of string - it may just be the place from where to trim.  Consider 3 spaces at the start of a string: "[space][space][space]string"... `ltrim(string, 2)`.  The code will find the start at 3, going *beyond* size of 2.  And, his while loop would crash the program.

Comment: @Blazes REALLY! See 3-th comment of answer bellow.

Comment: @Mihran - your ltrim code might be used by some other programmer in your company, or by anyone reading this page.  it is the job of `ltrim` to to ensure it does not go past `size`.  My point remains, the above code will crash as per my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding "safe" - you missed one important case - a check that you don't overrun the buffer. Use that `size` parameter to bound the loop.

Comment: Look at code again. It is checked (of course assuming that this function should get null terminated buffer).

Comment: That's the catch - what happens if it's not zero terminated? Or when `size` is less then number of characters before zero byte? You'd be lucky with a segfault :)

Comment: @Nikolai this is not full code. Actually this ltrim is a member function of some class which manipulates the buffer, and takes care the buffer is null terminated and also keeps its size cached (so there is no need to pass size as parameter)!

Comment: Well, we didn't know that, did we? In any case, you keep saying "reread the code" - but the code you posted does not check `str` parameter for `NULL` value, nor `size` for being negative. That's hardly qualifies as "safe". If you just want to prove to everybody that your code is perfect, this is the wrong site. Listen to what people are saying, you'd do much better.

Comment: Agree @Nikolai my code have lots of issues. But if someone is asking question and posting code like `int a = b;` you  don't tell him, that b should be declared and initialized, right?

Comment: Yes and no. Here people usually ask for minimal *complete* code that exhibits whatever the question is about. Your particular question was "is this code safe?". The straight answer is "no, not as we see it". You should actually update the question itself with all the assumptions you are adding in comments. That would make for better answers too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    memcpy(str, start, end-start);
```

If you [`memmove`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/memmove.html) (see [Paul R.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468622/shifting-buffer-via-memcpy/6468657#6468657)) 1 more character, that extra character is the null terminator.